# Html Input boxes must be in the same line

Tags: html, css, html-table

Do you see the rec tangled red text box which is under "Acil Durumda Aranacak Kişi",
I want that text box just near "212" since they are both for telephone number...

How can I do that?

[alt text http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/1058/rrrrzh.jpg](http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/1058/rrrrzh.jpg)

PS: All the html text boxes, and inputs are created by c# code...

Comment: add some html code because with this it is impossible to help you

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **nowrap** on the TD tag, eg

```
<td class="TaskForField" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> ... </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css property `float:left;` for both of them even if I suggest you first to give us some code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a text value of " " (i.e. an empty space) to the label immediately before the 2nd telephone control.

This should add a non-breakable space into the span element (the .net label) before the input element (the 2nd telephone textbox control) which would cause it to display in the browser and occupy the same space as the other labels - thus aligning the textbox control with the others.

Failing that you could define a class in your stylesheet with a margin-left property and then apply this to your textbox using the cssClass property.